# Using Pest.rs how can I manage a multi-line syntax where a line ends in "\"?

Tags: rust, newline, grammar, peg, pest

A common idiom for bash is is to use `\` to escape the newline at the end of the line,

> If a `\<newline>` pair appears, and the backslash is not itself quoted, the `\<newline>` is  treated as a line continuation (that is, it is removed from the input stream and effectively ignored).

Such that

```
FOO \
BAR
```

is the same as,

```
FOO BAR
```

How would I write this grammar into pest.rs? Note this means that NEWLINE is significant in my grammar, and I can't merely ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to set your

```
WHITESPACE = { ( " "* ~ "\\" ~ NEWLINE ~ " "* ) }
```

This keeps regular newlines significant unless they're prefixed by `\`.